# A continuous onto/surjective function from $[0, 1) \to \Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Does there exist a continuous onto/surjective function from $[0, 1) \to \Bbb R$?

Finding difficult to site an example...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about $f\colon[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}\sin\frac{1}{1-x}?$$

Comment: how did you construct the example??

Comment: I was trying to think of something oscillating! (+1) Cool!

Comment: @user8795 Examples of this sort are quite common: $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ and similar expressions are nice, as they will change sign increasingly faster near a point while still being bounded... it only remains to modulate with another expression to have their amplitude go up as well.

Comment: @user8795 I think it's kind of visual. You need a function nicely defined at zero, but somehow it needs to go to both $\pm \infty$ as it approaches $1$, hence you need something going to $\infty$ at $1$, like $\frac{1}{1-x}$, and something to make it oscillate, to cover all positives and negatives! Hence a $\sin$

Comment: @ArticChar Not certain I agree with the edit for the punctuation, however... I liked the interrogation mark where it was. :)